# List all files in a directory matching a string and copy output

Tags: command-line, terminal, cygwin, find, grep

I'm trying to create a series of playlists on my MP3 player, running Rockbox, by finding a file matching a string, using `find /cygdrive/g/MUSIC -type f -name "Search Criteria" | /cygdrive/g/PLAYLIST/Playlist Name.m3u8`.
When I search using `$ find /cygdrive/g/Music -type f -name "*Theme*"`, my results are:

```
/cygdrive/g/Music/Movie Masterpieces/14 - 1900's Theme.ogg
/cygdrive/g/Music/Movie Masterpieces/02 - Deborah's Theme.ogg
/cygdrive/g/Music/Star Trek_ The Motion Picture [Disc 1]/01 - Ilia's Theme.ogg
```

However, I would like to be able to search for any folder and output the names of the files inside, for an output similar to:

```
/cygdrive/g/Music/Cult Themes/01 - The Avengers (1965).ogg       
/cygdrive/g/Music/Cult Themes/02 - Man In A Suitcase (1968).ogg  
/cygdrive/g/Music/Cult Themes/03 - The Saint (1962).ogg
```

I have access to both a Linux terminal, cygwin or Windows command prompt, and would be grateful for any solution, but if possible in one or two lines.

Edit:  After receiving the a number of solutions, I've found the best solution was:

```
find /cygdrive/g/MUSIC -type d -iname "*theme*" -print -prune 
| xargs -d '\n' -I {} find {} -name '*.ogg'
```

This solution was able to complete the search the quickest, and whilst it may not be as brief as the first response, is still succinct.  Thanks to all who responded!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to process `find` output is *not* `for`, but to read it line by line:

```
find . -type d -iname '*themes*' -print -prune |
while read -r path; do
    find "$path" -name '*.ogg'
done
```

or

```
find . -type d -iname '*themes*' -print -prune |
xargs -d '\n' -I {} find {} -name '*.ogg'
```

or let `find` do it:

```
find . -type d -iname '*themes*' -exec find {} -name '*.ogg' \; -prune
```

---

`-prune` is a simple safeguard against cases where both a parent directory and a subdirectory match the `-iname` rule.

I skipped the traditional `-print0 | xargs -d '\0'` since filenames with newline characters are very, very unlikely to exist on a FAT32 filesystem.

Comment: You could also set `IFS=$'\n'` and then `read line`, but that breaks on wildcards too when you use the filename again, so … yeah. `exec` would be the most concise option.

Comment: @slhck: `read` does not process wildcards, so I don't see how would it break when using `read line`. (The only place I can see is during *expansion* of the variable, which can be solved by double-quoting.)

Comment: Yeah I meant expansion, it wasn't the case for your answer anyway. Just something that can be easily forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to search for a dir (eg. themes), and list all the .ogg files under it (recursively):

```
for x in $(find . -iname "*themes*"); do find $x -iname "*.ogg"; done
```

I think you can customize this example for your needs, if it's not what you exactly want.

Comment: That almost works, once brackets are added `for x in $( find ... ); do ...`, but does not work if folders have spaces in their names.  Thanks for the quick response, if I get any further I'll put the solution up.

Comment: Will definitely break on spaces in file names, also beware of globbing characters when using `$x` again.